# Facebook Share button wont recognize embedded video

Tags: facebook, youtube

I have a facebook share button on my website and it works great on everything else except for embedded videos from youtube. When I click on the share button it only loads the title and whatever the excerpt is with out the thumbnail of the video. Please can someone help on this problem? My entire site depends on it.

Comment: IF this question is WordPress-related, it is far too localized for WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the meta og:video tags into your header for it to recognize them.

Simple Facebook Connect does this automagically for YouTube content: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

More info on OpenGraph tags here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is not WordPress related. Still, regarding the question, I think Facebook includes a thumbnail to the video when you share a link to a YouTube video, not a page that contains a YouTube video (as would be the case in your website).

Anyway, you'll probably have better luck asking this on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am using a wordpress theme, it almost seems as if the share button doesn't recognize the embedded video

Comment: @Bob Love: I believe you have specify (somehow) a special string of proposed thumbnails that facebook can use. I'm not 100% sure as I've not really dealt with anything beyond adding a like button to posts. :/

Comment: Can I maybe add anything to the share button php code (meta code) to make it work?